# Workflow Manager Server 'Faulting application name : Microsoft.Workflow.ServiceHost.exe'

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-2013

Getting error on workflow Manager server under event logs.

Application Event log id is 1000

Faulting application name: Microsoft.Workflow.ServiceHost.exe, version: 1.0.40131.0, time stamp: 0x52ef34e1
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18409, time stamp: 0x5315a05a
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000000000000940d
Faulting process id: 0x1628
Faulting application start time: 0x01d04cd5b966ad0a
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Workflow Manager\1.0\Workflow\Artifacts\Microsoft.Workflow.ServiceHost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 277be834-b8c9-11e4-a2ae-0050569d29be

.NET Runtime log id :- 1026

Application: Microsoft.Workflow.ServiceHost.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: Microsoft.Workflow.Common.FatalException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.Fx+<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Regards,

Rahul

Answer (score 0):

The issue appear because of Microsoft.Activities.Hosting dll. To resolve this issue please use the below steps
1. Stop Workflow backend service.
2. Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.dll is crashing. You need to change this dll. Please ask Microsoft to share the dll with you. And then replace this dll to C:\Program Files\Workflow Manager\1.0\Workflow\Artifacts and C:\Program Files\Workflow Manager\1.0\Workflow\WFWebRoot\bin. 
3.Start->Run->type "services.msc"  and find the workflow backend service, start that service it will work fine and you will not get this error message again.

If the issue still persist you have to raise the ticket with Microsoft .
Hope this will resolve your issue.